# Ethernet network disconnected after hard reset

Tags: 16.04, networking

My PC is a little bit wonky. I need to hard reset it often during the boot sequence because the display would receive no signal. The latest hard reset seemed to have broken my wireless driver. I'm using "TP-LINK Archer T4U v1.0" and have downloaded and installed the package `rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux`, and it has worked up until the latest bootup, but now the Ethernet Network always shows as **disconnected** and I don't know how to uninstall or repair the driver.

What can I do?

Edit: Here is the wireless-info:

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 30 Sep 2017 11:18 CEST +0200

Booted last: 30 Sep 2017 00:00 CEST +0200

Script from: 25 Mar 2017 07:04 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu Description: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS Release: 16.04 Codename: xenial

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.10.0-35-generic #39~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Sep 13 09:02:42 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 01)  Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1043:8385]  Kernel driver in use: r8169

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2357:0101   Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub Bus 004 Device 002: ID 1d57:fa60 Xenta  Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

##### lsmod #############################

cfg80211              602112  0 wmi                    16384  0

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

enp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'enp3s0' [IF1]>  
          inet addr:192.168.178.47  Bcast:192.168.178.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::5d4e:610f:100f:992d/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: 2003:71:ef6c:bf00:4bb2:9ae3:d03c:58b2/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: 2003:71:ef6c:bf00:b50b:710:6935:9424/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2748 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2003 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:4004358 (4.0 MB)  TX bytes:152363 (152.3 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1718 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1718 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:128596 (128.5 KB)  TX bytes:128596 (128.5 KB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp3s0    no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table Destination     Gateway         Genmask        Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.178.1   0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp3s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp3s0
192.168.178.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp3s0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1 search fritz.box

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       830     1  0 11:12 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp3s0 GENERAL.TYPE:           ethernet GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller GENERAL.DRIVER:                    r8169 GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 2.3LK-NAPI GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:                GENERAL.HWADDR:               <MAC 'enp3s0' [IF1]> GENERAL.MTU:                            1500 GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected) GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given) GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:06.0/0000:03:00.0/net/enp3s0 GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       enp3s0 GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:    no GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:    yes GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:      
-- GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 1 GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       ea18de39-bc37-35b8-9634-b29f75f83bac GENERAL.CON-PATH:                 /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/0 GENERAL.METERED:    no (guessed) CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     100 Mb/s CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:   on CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{2} CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   ea18de39-bc37-35b8-9634-b29f75f83bac | Wired connection 1 IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.178.47/24 IP4.GATEWAY:
192.168.178.1 IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000 IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.178.1 IP4.DOMAIN[1]:                          fritz.box DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_subnet_mask = 1 DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1 DHCP4.OPTION[3]:         subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0 DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        domain_name_servers = 192.168.178.1 DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                   ip_address = 192.168.178.47 DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_static_routes = 1 DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.178.1 DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                requested_time_offset = 1 DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        broadcast_address = 192.168.178.255 DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                  requested_interface_mtu = 1 DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       dhcp_rebinding_time = 756000 DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1 DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                    dhcp_message_type = 5 DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       requested_broadcast_address = 1 DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                      routers = 192.168.178.1 DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       dhcp_renewal_time = 432000 DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_domain_name = 1 DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       domain_name = fritz.box DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       requested_routers = 1 DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       expiry = 1507627055 DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_wpad = 1 DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_netbios_scope = 1 DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1 DHCP4.OPTION[24]:             requested_netbios_name_servers = 1 DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                   network_number = 192.168.178.0 DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       requested_domain_search = 1 DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       next_server = 192.168.178.1 DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       ntp_servers = 192.168.178.1 DHCP4.OPTION[29]:                       requested_host_name = 1 DHCP4.OPTION[30]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 864000 DHCP4.OPTION[31]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1 IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         2003:71:ef6c:bf00:b50b:710:6935:9424/64 IP6.ADDRESS[2]:                2003:71:ef6c:bf00:4bb2:9ae3:d03c:58b2/64 IP6.ADDRESS[3]:               fe80::5d4e:610f:100f:992d/64 IP6.GATEWAY:                            fe80::3681:c4ff:feb2:41d4 IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst
= 2003:71:ef6c:bf00::/56, nh = fe80::3681:c4ff:feb2:41d4, mt = 100 IP6.DNS[1]:                             fd00::3681:c4ff:feb2:41d4 DHCP6.OPTION[1]:                        requested_dhcp6_domain_search
= 1 DHCP6.OPTION[2]:                        dhcp6_name_servers = fd00::3681:c4ff:feb2:41d4 DHCP6.OPTION[3]:                        dhcp6_server_id = 0:3:0:1:<MAC address> DHCP6.OPTION[4]:               requested_dhcp6_client_id = 1 DHCP6.OPTION[5]:                        requested_dhcp6_name_servers = 1 DHCP6.OPTION[6]:                      dhcp6_unknown_86 = 20:3:0:71:ef:6c:bf:0:36:81:c4:ff:fe:b2:41:d4 DHCP6.OPTION[7]:                        dhcp6_client_id = 0:4:a3:c0:26:f2:d6:54:b3:93:f3:a3:d9:89:8d:cb:43:66

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main] NetworkingEnabled=true WirelessEnabled=true WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main] plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown] managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Kirbys-Dreamland 1]] (600 root) [connection] id=Kirbys-Dreamland 1 | type=wifi | permissions=user:minecraft-client:; [wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Kirbys-Dreamland [ipv4] method=auto [ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Kirbys-Dreamland]] (600 root) [connection] id=Kirbys-Dreamland | type=wifi | permissions=user:minecraft:; [wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Kirbys-Dreamland [ipv4] method=auto [ipv6] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Europe/Berlin (based on set time zone)

country 00: DFS-UNSET   (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR     (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, NO-IR    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR     (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR   (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR  (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR     (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

enp3s0    no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp3s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[cfg80211] filename:       /lib/modules/4.10.0-35-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko description:    wireless configuration support license:        GPL author:         Johannes Berg srcversion:     D77C8F93375950F3BA95B16 depends:         intree:         Y vermagic:       4.10.0-35-generic SMP mod_unload  parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int) parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp) parm:      cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[cfg80211] bss_entries_limit: 1000 cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf] blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf] blacklist evbug blacklist usbmouse blacklist usbkbd blacklist eepro100 blacklist de4x5 blacklist eth1394 blacklist snd_intel8x0m blacklist snd_aw2 blacklist i2c_i801 blacklist prism54 blacklist bcm43xx blacklist garmin_gps blacklist asus_acpi blacklist snd_pcsp blacklist pcspkr blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf] alias net-pf-3 off alias net-pf-6 off alias net-pf-9 off alias net-pf-11 off alias net-pf-12 off alias net-pf-19 off alias net-pf-21 off alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf] remove iwlwifi \ (/sbin/lsmod | grep -o
-e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \ && /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf] softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[   16.388770] rtl8812au: version magic '4.10.0-28-generic SMP mod_unload ' should be '4.10.0-35-generic SMP mod_unload ' [  
20.047119] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp3s0: link is not ready [   20.063660] r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: link down [   20.063701] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp3s0: link is not ready [  306.000242] r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: link up [  306.000261] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp3s0: link becomes ready

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: However the connection symbol still shows up as the WiFi symbol, so the driver can't be completely broken. It just doesn't detect the WiFi stick anymore.

Comment: are you having issues with wifi or issues with Ethernet?  (Wireless sometimes shows as Ethernet due to some drivers)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result? I know it may seem a bit overwhelming for a novice but your info so far is a bit vague and the diagnostics will likely cover all options that may cause your issue. Thanks.

Comment: I still have the issue. Does anyone knwo what to do about it?